# How to make two classes which both have method with the same name, signature and return type behave like they would implement the same interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, java-8

I will explain my question on an example.

I have two classes `NumberGeneratorApple` and `NumberGeneratorOrange`. Both of them have method with the same signature and return type `public Integer getNumber()`. The problem is they do not implement the same interface althought it would be logical. I could make interface with this method and modify these classes to implement it but I don't want to do so. Here is why. These classes are generated automatically from let's say xml. In real example there are dozens of such classes. We have to generate them from time to time and it overwrites the old ones. I don't want to change each class manually to implement interface after each generation. Also it might not be obvious that it should be done for some other person working on the same project and even for me after some time.
Here is the first class:

```
public class NumberGeneratorApple {
    public Integer getNumber(){
        return 9;
    }
}
```

and the second one:

```
public class NumberGeneratorOrange {
    public Integer getNumber(){
        return 19;
    }
}
```

Althought they don't implement the same interface I need to use them in a generic way. I just want to do something like this:

```
public class ClassThatOperates<T extends NumberGeneratorInterface> {
    T generator;

    public ClassThatOperates(T generator) {
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    public void doSomeOperation(){
        //Obviously it won't work for NumberGeneratorApple and NumberGeneratorOrange
        // because they do not implement NumberGeneratorInterface
        //And if I change "<T extends NumberGeneratorInterface>" to "<T>"
        // I cannot write method call "generator.getNumber()"
        System.out.print("The number with constant is: ");
        System.out.println(generator.getNumber() + 5);
    }
}
```

This is the interface (I know public is not necessary there and it is there by default. I just want to emphasize it):

```
public interface NumberGeneratorInterface {
    public Integer getNumber();
}
```

As you can see it is impossible to do such thing because neither `NumberGeneratorApple` nor `NumberGeneratorOrange` implements `NumberGeneratorInterface`. However I came up with some solution but following my instinct I think it is rather poor. I made wrapper classes:

```
public class NumberGeneratorAppleWrapper extends NumberGeneratorApple implements NumberGeneratorInterface {
}
```

and

```
public class NumberGeneratorOrangeWrapper extends NumberGeneratorOrange implements NumberGeneratorInterface {
}
```

It is a little bit tricky. It might be not obvious at first but when you call getNumber() on object of one of this classes you call in fact something like this:

```
@Override
public Integer getNumber() {
    return super.getNumber();
}
```

Now I can call it this way:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassThatOperates<NumberGeneratorAppleWrapper> classThatOperatesApple = new ClassThatOperates<>(new NumberGeneratorAppleWrapper());
        ClassThatOperates<NumberGeneratorOrangeWrapper> classThatOperatesOrange = new ClassThatOperates<>(new NumberGeneratorOrangeWrapper());
        classThatOperatesApple.doSomeOperation();
        classThatOperatesOrange.doSomeOperation();
    }
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
The number with constant is: 14
The number with constant is: 24
```

The advantage of such approach instead of adding manually `implements NumberGeneratorInterface` to each generated class is that We don't have to repeat the same work after each generation (which overrides old classes). We only have to add a new wrapper when generation results in some new, additional class.

I know that in such scenario I can get rid of generics in `ClassThatOperates` and just declare `NumberGeneratorInterface generator;` without `<T extends...>` and so on (and I even should) so the code would be simpler, but I want to make this example quite similar to what I found in some real project. I wrote: I have, I made, I came up etc. but in fact it is based on the already existing code that I found in some project.

There are my questions:
1. Is there a better solution?
2. Is this solution a so called "bad taste"?
3. If I have to use such solution maybe my whole approach is wrong?
4. If there is no better solution even if the whole approach is wrong what could be improved in this code (including getting rid of generics)?

Comment: You could also use reflection. Not sure however if that'd be better than your approach

Comment: Probably reflection is a way to go but I think It might be quite compicated and in result worse than this approach especially when it comes to cleanliness of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is there a better solution?

Your solution looks good to me.  You have used the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), which uses existing functionality to conform to an otherwise unrelated interface.  Without changing `NumberGeneratorApple` and `NumberGeneratorOrange`, you have adapted those classes' functionality to `NumberGeneratorInterface`.

More generally, you can have existing methods with different signatures be adapted to an interface, e.g. if you had

```
public class NumberGeneratorApple {
    public Integer getAppleNumber(){
        return 9;
    }
}
```

Then your adapter class would explicitly call `getAppleNumber` when implementing the interface.

```
public class NumberGeneratorAppleWrapper extends NumberGeneratorApple implements NumberGeneratorInterface {
    @Override
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return getAppleNumber();
    }
}
```

> 2. Is this solution a so called "bad taste"?

This solution leaves no bad taste.  The Adapter Pattern is a well established software design pattern.

> 3. If I have to use such solution maybe my whole approach is wrong?

If you cannot change existing classes such as `NumberGeneratorApple`, then the Adapter Pattern is the way to go.  If you can change them, then just have the classes implement the necessary interface directly.

```
public class NumberGeneratorApple implements NumberGeneratorInterface {
    @Override
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return 9;
    }
}
```

Or, if the method signature is different:

```
public class NumberGeneratorApple implements NumberGeneratorInterface {
    public Integer getAppleNumber() {
        return 9;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return getAppleNumber();
    }
}
```

> 4. If there is no better solution even if the whole approach is wrong what could be improved in this code (including getting rid of generics)?

If your classes such as `NumberGeneratorApple` really have exactly one method, and are not just simplifications of more complex classes with multiple methods for the purposes of this question, then you can use method references as another answer has hinted.  Instead of declaring your own interface `NumberGeneratorInterface`, a method reference can be typed as a `Supplier<Integer>`.

```
public class ClassThatOperates {
    Supplier<Integer> generator;

    public ClassThatOperates(Supplier<Integer> generator) {
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    public void doSomeOperation(){
        System.out.print("The number with constant is: ");
        System.out.println(generator.get() + 5);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
NumberGeneratorOrange ngo = new NumberGeneratorOrange();
ClassThatOperates cto = new ClassThatOperates(ngo::getNumber);
cto.doSomeOperation();
```

Comment: Ad 4. This solution would make sense if there was only one method in classes such as `NumberGeneratorApple`. But as you noted this example is only simplification of more complex case in which such classes have more than one method to be adapted. So in my real case such solution cannot be used. Thanks for mentioning that this Supplier solution could be used only in a specific scenario.

Answer (score 3):

With java8 you can instantiate one of your custom classes

```
NumberGeneratorApple apple = new NumberGeneratorApple();
```

and create a generic supplier from it:

```
Supplier<Integer> numberGenerator = apple::getNumber;
```

then you can pass it around or do whatever you need with it:

```
Integer number = numberGenerator.get();
externalObject.execute(numberGenerator);
```

How's that sound?

Comment: Your solution is good but only in this simplified case. In my real case there are many similar methods in `NumberGeneratorApple` and `NumberGeneratorApple` and It probably makes no sense to use such solution. However this answer is correct and may help other people having similar problem.

Comment: Then without having a common interface or a parent class there will be no automatic solution. Whichever approach you choose, you will need to handle each of the methods coding it up separately. So for example creating a Generator class and implement all these methods by either supplying functional interfaces implementations for them (Functions, Suppliers, Consumers..), or use composition and delegate all the calls to the implementation object (NumberGeneratorApple) inside this class using reflection.
more on Reflection API
docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Comment: The solutions suggested in my above comment will work for every newly generated class, using adapter pattern there would be extra work - adapting each of the generated class explicitly

Comment: I agree this solution will work even for more sophisticated case. But let's say we have five methods. In this case we have to pass five arguments to the constructor. It is a little bit too much and if all or some of the arguments have the same type let's say Supplier<Integer> we can accidentally pass them in the wrong order. The main class gets responsibility of adapter to redirect calls to adequate methods. It maybe even violates Single Responsibility Principle. So it might be better to hide everything in adapter class and pass only one argument to the constructor. What do you think?

Comment: Perhaps using builder pattern would help, so creation could look like:
Generator gen=new Generator.Builder().withNumberGen(apple::getNumber).withFeature2(apple::feature2).withFeature3(apple::feature3).build();

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
class ClassThatOperates
{
    final Supplier<Integer> m_generator;

    ClassThatOperates(Supplier<Integer> generator)
    {
        m_generator = generator;
    }
    void doSomething()
    {
        ...
        m_generator.get();
    }
}

NumberGeneratorApple nga = new NumberGeneratorApple();
ClassThatOperates cta = new ClassThatOperates(nga::generate);
```

Comment: Your solution is good but only in this simplified case. In my real case there are many similar methods in `NumberGeneratorApple` and `NumberGeneratorApple` and It probably makes no sense to use such solution. However this answer is correct and may help other people having similar problem.

Comment: In that case your solution is not bad, but you may want to avoid defining all those adapter classes by constructing anonymous classes like `NumberGenerator ng = new NumberGeneratorApple implements NumberGenerator {};`  Java will recognize what you have in `NumberGeneratorApple` as implementations of what you need in `NumberGenerator`